Powershell script for find/replace multiple items in a batch file
I am trying to write a powershell script that will take IP addresses (subnets) in a batch file and replace them with an updated value.  I am using the following code but the replacements are not all being done correctly, some of them are just incorrect values and then they have added characters at the end.  I am trying to just do a one-for-one replacement on the subnet value.  Here is an example of my code:
# Define the path to your batch file
$batchFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\batchfile.bat"

# Read the content of the batch file
$batchFileContent = Get-Content -Path $batchFilePath

# Define the replacements
$replacements = @{
    "oldString1" = "newString1"
    "oldString2" = "newString2"
    # Add more replacements as needed
}

# Perform the replacements
foreach ($oldString in $replacements.Keys) {
    $batchFileContent = $batchFileContent -replace [regex]::Escape($oldString), $replacements[$oldString]
}

# Write the updated content back to the batch file
$batchFileContent | Set-Content -Path $batchFilePath

For the values "oldString1" and "newString1" these are replaced with the IP addresses accordingly.  I just did not want to share that information here.
Can anyone see why this would not work properly?  If you need more details I am happy to provide what I can without providing any proprietary information.  Thanks!
see above for example code and issues encountered
Adding a minimal reproduceable example:
using the code below:
# Define the path to your batch file
$batchFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\batchfile.bat"

# Read the content of the batch file
$batchFileContent = Get-Content -Path $batchFilePath

# Define the replacements
$replacements = @{
    "10.44.189" = "10.225.8"
    "10.44.223" = "10.225.16"
    # Add more replacements as needed
}

# Perform the replacements
foreach ($oldString in $replacements.Keys) {
    $batchFileContent = $batchFileContent -replace [regex]::Escape($oldString), $replacements[$oldString]
}

# Write the updated content back to the batch file
$batchFileContent | Set-Content -Path $batchFilePath

Instead, 10.44.189 gets replaced with 10.229.18689, and 10.44.223 gets replaced with 10.229.18690.  Examples below from batch file:
Before replace:
:S063
SET OCT1=10.44.189
SET OCT2=10.44.189
SET OCT3=10.44.189
SET T1=172.18.211.5
SET NORO=NO
set orpos=YES
SET PRINTER=HP
GOTO CALLCOMMANDS
GOTO END

:S067
SET OCT1=10.44.223
SET OCT2=10.44.223
SET OCT3=10.44.223
SET T1=172.18.211.9
SET NORO=NO
set orpos=YES
SET PRINTER=HP
GOTO CALLCOMMANDS
GOTO END

After replace:
    :S063
    SET OCT1=10.229.18689
    SET OCT2=10.229.18689
    SET OCT3=10.229.18689
    SET T1=172.18.211.5
    SET NORO=NO
    set orpos=YES
    SET PRINTER=HP
    GOTO CALLCOMMANDS
    GOTO END
    
    :S067
SET OCT1=10.229.2223
SET OCT2=10.229.2223
SET OCT3=10.229.2223
SET T1=172.18.231.41
SET NORO=NO
set orpos=YES
SET PRINTER=HP
GOTO CALLCOMMANDS
GOTO END


There's no obvious problem with your code. Describe in what way,  specifically, it doesn't work. As an aside: You can make the code more efficient by using -Raw with Get-Content - to read the file into memory as a single, multiline string -  which then requires you add -NoNewLine to the Set-Content call.

Also, to avoid false positives, use ... -replace ('\b' + [regex]::Escape($oldString) + '\b'), $replacements[$oldString]

Thanks, I know it is hard without the results - I just didn't want to share all of the IPs, but I will share a few that for sure did not replace correctly and see if that helps.  For instance, one of the replaces is "10.44.189" = "10.225.8".  In the actual file, 10.44.189 gets replaced with 10.229.18689 - I have no idea where that is coming from.

That's mysterious. I suspect that no one will be able to help you without an [mcve].

Thanks for updating, but your update lacks the reproducible aspect: Running the code with the specified input does not produce the results you're showing (at least for me, but I still don't see how it could result in what you're showing).

Sorry - I made a correction - so I am just pulling two examples from the batch file.  They are excerpts from (batch file 1: before replace), and after I run the code, that is what the resulting batch file looks like (batch file 1: after replace).

If there is a secure place I can upload the actual batch file to help with this, I am happy to do so.

I just needed to implement this in my code:  thank you @mklement0 -

Also, to avoid false positives, use
... -replace ('\b' + [regex]::Escape($oldString) + '\b'), $replacements[$oldString]

It all works now.  Thanks!

I have done this in the past and this is the way I do it.
# Define the path to your batch file
$batchFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\batchfile.bat"

# Read the content of the batch file
$batchFileContent = Get-Content -Path $batchFilePath

# Define the replacements
$NewFileContent1 = $batchFileContent.Replace('192.168.10.100','10.200.30.46')
Set-Content -Value $NewFileContent1 -Path $batchFilePath -Force
$NewFileContent2 = $NewFileContent1.Replace('192.168.10.55','10.10.133.18')
Set-Content -Value $NewFileContent2 -Path $batchFilePath -Force

Optionally you could be more aggressive and use multiple "Replace" methods on one line.
$NewFileContent1 = $batchFileContent.Replace('192.168.10.100','10.200.30.46').Replace('192.1686.10.55','10.10.133.18')

Important Note: since IP Addresses are numbers it should not matter however since you didn't share your actual value I want to be sure and tell you that the strings in the replace method overload are indeed case sensitive. So for example 'cat' does not equal 'CAT' so if there are alpha characters in the string then be sure to match case inside the overload parenthesis.

Thank you!  There are no alpha characters in the strings.  Just numbers and periods.  I know it is hard without the results - I just didn't want to share all of the IPs, but I will share a few that for sure did not replace correctly and see if that helps. For instance, one of the replaces is "10.44.189" = "10.225.8". In the actual file, 10.44.189 gets replaced with 10.229.18689 - I have no idea where that is coming from.

This approach is inherently brittle, because it has the potential to replace false positives; e.g., with .Replace('192.168.10.10', '10.200.30.46') an IP address in the input string such as 192.168.10.101 would match too. Also: it's not clear why there  are two Set-Content calls; the approach is less elegant due to needing a separate .Replace() call with literals for each replacement. Taking a step back: Not addressing the question being asked and simply offering a different approach without explaining why it should be preferred over the approach in the question is ill-advised.

Thank you, and that does make sense - what type of replace call would I want to use to avoid the false positives?

I think you hit the nail on the head for at least some of the issues, @mklement0 - I have added a reproduceable example to the post.

I have thousands of replacements - so I need an easy way to just have them in a text file or something, which is what I am doing now.  Then I just copy/paste them into the replacements section.

@Ryane can you confirm that if you use your own minimal reproducible code as posted above against the sample "before replace" bat file posted above you still get the wrong output? Have you tested your MRE?

@Doofus yes I have.  I get the output that I posted.

It makes zero sense to me.  If there is a place I can upload the actual files I am happy to do so.

@Ryane - The fact that the MRE is working correctly for me, but not for you. is concerning. I`m not able to test the proposed fix. I have to think there is more code at play that just what appears in the MRE. I know there can be differences between versions of Powershell but such a simple script should surely be consistent for most users?

I am not sure why that was happening, but it is fixed now, I resolved the issue with @mklement0 - thank you!
